# UITableView visible area blank when cells stored in array instead of reusing

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView into which I populate a small number of static UITableViewCells (about 6 cells). I am not using storyboards. Each of these cells is a custom UITableViewCell, has a different layout, so I my thought is that cell reuse is never going to happen in this case.

So I am creating these cells beforehand and storing them into an NSArray. In cellForRowIndexAtPath I just return the corresponding cell that is already stored in my array.

Everything works fine with this approach on iOS6. However on iOS7, the visible area of the table view goes completely blank. When I scroll up, the part of the table view that was underneath the main view previously shows the cells (partial cell if the cell was partially underneath before). But the initial visible area of the table view still remains blank.

Two questions here - Is it fine to store the cells in an NSArray and return them in cellForRowAtIndexPath? As I mentioned earlier, the number of cells is small and each cell is unique, no reuse is going to happen while scrolling.
And what is going wrong in IOS7?

Comment: If you're using a static table view, you shouldn't even be implementing cellForRowAtIndexPath (or any other data source method).

Comment: The cells are static, but the table view is not. I might have any number of cells (but maximum 6) in the table view.And I am not using storyboards

Comment: You should be able to store cells in an NSArray just fine. I think the issue has something to do with certain rendering not occurring or occurring too late. Can you post some code showing how you initialize a cell? Also, when are you initializing the cells?

Comment: I removed all autolayout constraints from the table view in the xib and the problem went away. Even if I add a single autolayout constraint of any type, the problem reappears. There is no programmatic autolayout code that I am using, so frame manipulation, no errors are shown the console